# How to move multiple selected items from listview to another listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-widget

I have two listviews [SAMPLE IMAGE HERE](http://oi43.tinypic.com/2zo9aug.jpg).i want to move items from one listview to another.
i have two buttons,"move to right" and "move to left".
Its a multi selection listview.after select items we need to move this items to another listview.

First listview data from database.code shown below

```
public void fillcategory() {
            Cursor cursor = dataBase
                    .select("SELECT * FROM t_Category ORDER BY CategoryName");

            lacategory = new list(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, cursor,
                    new String[] { "CategoryName" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },1);
            lvcategory.setAdapter(lacategory);
            lvcategory.setOnItemClickListener(new listclick());
            lvcategory.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        }
```

Comment: Kannan I saw your photo, two listViews running in same activity or each listViews running separately activities?

Answer (score 3):

There are twio options you can do this, first by adding checkbox in each listitem and then populate the other listview with selected items. for this here is good tutorial [Multiple Check](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_selection)

Second, you can set you listview property to multiple_select in adapter and then populated those selected item through position in other listview. 
 I hope atleast one will work.

Comment: according to second -: i alredy set ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE.but how multiple_select in adapter.

Comment: you need to check if the listitem isSelected or not, I have checked it like this "if(sfsendmes.isSelected())" where sdsendmes is my listview class having all the data ..if you dont undertstand if give you detail example